# local variable df referenced before assignment (Bokeh Interactive Visualization)

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I just need a dropdown menu that shows all the departments and when we update the department it should generate the bar graph that gives all the products and it's corresponding retail value. 
But it's giving a box with no visualization and a dropdown list.
Error: "local variable 'df' referenced before assignment"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import math
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import  Dropdown
from bokeh.io import curdoc

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/austinejose/Desktop/My Files/Work/Newcastle Service Station/2018/Feb_Totals.csv')
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

names = [str(x) for x in df['Product Name']]
plot = figure(x_range = 'Product Name', plot_height = 500, width = 700, title = "Sales By Departments",
              toolbar_location = "below")
plot.vbar(x = "Product Name", top = "Retail Value", width = 0.9, source = source, color = 'deepskyblue')
plot.xgrid.grid_line_color = "white"
plot.y_range.start = 0
plot.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/4
plot.xaxis.axis_label = "Product"
plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Retail Value"
plot.axis.minor_tick_in = -3
plot.axis.minor_tick_out = 6
plot.outline_line_color = "black"

menu = [("Bill Pay", "Bill Pay"), ("Hot Food", "Hot Food")]

menu_select = Dropdown(label='Department' ,menu=menu)

def dropdown_click(attr, old, new):
    active_dropdown = menu_select.value

    if active_dropdown in df['Department']:
        df = df[df['Department']==active_dropdown]
    source.data = df

menu_select.on_change('value', dropdown_click)

layout = row(menu_select, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in your callback:

```
def dropdown_click(attr, old, new):
    active_dropdown = menu_select.value

    if active_dropdown in df['Department']:
        df = df[df['Department']==active_dropdown]
    source.data = df
```

If `active_dropdown in df['Department']` is *False*, then your code never defines `df` before trying to set `source.data = df`. This is the immediate cause of the message *Error: "local variable 'df' referenced before assignment"*.

One possible solution is to move the assignment inside the `if` block, so that the assignment only ever happens when `df` is guaranteed to exist. Otherwise, you need to figure out what you want to heppen when the condition is *False*.

However, there is also a Bokeh usage error you will need to fix as well. The value of `source.data` has to be a *plain Python dict*, not a Pandas DataFrame.